# How to put the most recent item of report to the right side of the chart?

Tags: dashboard, charts, report-chart

Here is a chart that I have and I am seeing in a dashboard. The x-axis is from the most recent to the past time.

I am looking for a way to reverse the x-axis. I want the rightmost to be November 2021 and items to the left would go to the past as much as the diagram allows in size. I can not change the order of the x-axis to "accending" because it would put the oldest item at the left edge and November 2021 will not be visible. I also saw [this solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43943/how-do-i-customize-the-order-of-my-x-axis-in-a-chart) but it makes the chart static and every month I have to modify it.

Can you please help me find a way to put November 2021 to the right without actually specifying months?
[image: chart]

Comment: Could you just limit the number of months being shown on the report and change the sorting?

Comment: @DanielHoechst how?

Comment: @DanielHoechst I don't know how to set a filter between today and last year on the same day? Notice that I want it to automatically understand today in the filter range.
I have the option of "Last 120 days" but I want the "Last 365 days" which doesn't exist in my options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter the oppoortunities so you only have the last 365 days, you can just add a filter. Note that you should add it as an additional filter, ignoring the prebuilt filter for Close Date that is included with an opportunity report.

If you add it as a filter, you can use a relative date filter and use things such as `LAST 365 DAYS` or `LAST 12 MONTHS`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

***+1*** for @Daniel Hoechst's comment. You can alter those chart's visual by using following way,

- Go to that dashboard,Click "Edit" button.
- Go to the report component click the edit option, as highlighted
  [image]
- then you can find the below settings in Left side for the report component,

[image]

- Use `Sort By` option (for the field `Close Date by Month`) to achieve *to put November 2021 to the right* and use the `Max Groups Displayed` to control the no. of months showing.
- And finally Click the `Save`button to confirm the change.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, this will show exactly the graph that is in the question. I would limit the number of months using a filter in the report and then sort ascending by date in the dashboard.

Comment: Sorry, I think this don't need to update in that report. Normally You can use dashboard's sort option to ASC and DESC for the specific field results, As per given report component, If the user apply `SORT` option to the field `Close Date by Month` means which will help to get the `Nov 2021` bar in right side I think.

Comment: @MohanRaj nope. your approach puts June 2016 to the left.

Comment: @MohanRaj 
Notice that I have already mentioned this matter in the question: "I can not change the order of the x-axis to accending because it would put the oldest item at the left edge and November 2021 will not be visible."

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee Hi Matin, thanks for the response, then please adjust `Max Group Displayed` into 12 it's shows the last 12 months means, this Nov 2021 to Nov 2020 OR if you need to view the data from 2016 means, you need to give the `Max Group Displayed` as 65, then it's included the data from 2016 (But note the report (which used for this dashboard need to include that amount data, otherwise those months are not shown). Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: @MohanRaj. Max Group Displayed would set the first 12 months, not the last ones.